# Cake PHP v0.2.6 from 2006 - site questions

Tags: cakephp

Today I was asked to work on a site using cake.  This site appears to be using ake version 0.2.6 from 2006.

This site was build by a college student.  Its convoluted to me.

I would like your pro tips on IF We should attempt to upgrade, or start fresh.

My real issue is that I have NEVER worked with Cake. EVER!

I am afraid that If I start this work i would not be able to finish it.

It also uses an extreme amount of SOAP.

Please advise.

Comment: +1 for starting over using Cake 2. Plus if you start over you can use whatever tech you want :)

Comment: i would suggest panic

Comment: Are you sure this is the current version of the cake core? All files have a @since tag in the docblocks that can point to old version in which the class was introduced first

Comment: hostmyimage.net/image/15ma6e198.jpg

this shows the version, but im not sure what version it is, can ou help?

Comment: As @ceeram suggests, this is probably *not* the actual version of your CakePHP. Look for a file called [`VERSION.txt`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3/cake/VERSION.txt) inside the cake directory, that should mention the right version. Apart from that, I would really consider re-developing that website using an up-to-date version of CakePHP, preferably 2.3. A lot of improvements have been made since 2006

Answer (score 0):

If the cake version is too old like that, I recommend to start over. The newer versions have made *a lot* of improvement and upgrading from that to say version 2.3 I think just isn't worth the trouble, really.

Besides, if you've never worked with cake, I think you'll get confused trying to make v0.2.6 to 2.3 because of all the changes. It'll be a testimony to your courage not to throw the towel.

If you decide to start over, you should consider if cake is the right thing for you (you'll have to do a revamp of everything, you might as well consider other fw options). The great thing I found when I started working with cake was the documentation, so you'll be fine if you maintain that path.

And SOAP... it should consume SOAP ws or make them available? I've work with cake & soap, so it's definitely doable, but you also have to take that into consideration and see if maybe other framework will make that work easier.

So, conclusion: start fresh, almost always good :)
And investigate a little bit around to see if the new version of cake is the right alternative for you based on your needs (no one really can decide that except for you).